# PHP Mysqli Script Undefine Offset

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a script that will check for 3 random rows when executed and I need these 3 rows to have their own defined value for further use. The script I've written works as it should except I'm getting an Undefined offset: 1 and Undefined offset: 2 for the row variables. If it wasn't for these errors I could just ignore it but I'm having the script run through task manager at a set time and the error is causing it to not complete.

I've already been researching and trying to find relevant information but perhaps I'm not searching for the correct terminology.

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT szName, ip, dwRoleID FROM log_item, gamedata, `user` WHERE dwParam3 = '667287791' and gamedata.dwID = log_item.dwRoleID and gamedata.szName = `user`.`Name` GROUP BY `user`.ip ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3") or die(mysqli_error($db));
while ($row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$id1 = $row[0]['dwRoleID'];
$id2 = $row[1]['dwRoleID'];
$id3 = $row[2]['dwRoleID'];
$Winner1 = $row[0]['szName'];
$Winner2 = $row[1]['szName'];
$Winner3 = $row[2]['szName'];

$query2 = mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM log_item WHERE dwRoleID IN ('$id1', '$id2', '$id3') and dwParam3 = '667287791'") or die(mysqli_error($db));

}

$msg = "Congratulations

$Winner1, $Winner2 and $Winner3 have won the giveaway.

Winners have 12 hours to claim their reward or a new winner will be picked.";
$curl = curl_init('https://');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('content' => $msg)));
curl_exec($curl);
```

I know its the row output format that is wrong but it's doing exactly what I want it to with the except of the errors.

Comment: It only runs locally by task scheduler on the system and not accessible any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the while loop wrong. On first iteration there will be only one element in array $row at index 0. That's why index 1 and 2 are missing.

Try this:

```
while ($row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    // empty
}

$id1 = $row[0]['dwRoleID'];
$id2 = $row[1]['dwRoleID'];
$id3 = $row[2]['dwRoleID'];
$Winner1 = $row[0]['szName'];
$Winner2 = $row[1]['szName'];
$Winner3 = $row[2]['szName'];

$query2 = mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM log_item WHERE dwRoleID IN ('$id1', '$id2', '$id3') and dwParam3 = '667287791'") or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

**UPDATE 2018-08-10**: Use fetch_all instead (thanks Dharman)

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Comment: I changed it as you said and I'm still getting the 2 Undefined offsets.

Comment: Are you sure your query yields more than one record?

Comment: Actually it's working now, I had put the wrong variable to search for and it wasn't returning the correct amount and its working as it should be now. Thanks!

Comment: Why the loop? You could just fetch_all